# Kotlin+Dagger2+Retrofit+Named

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, named-scope

Im trying to build two different Retrofit objects pointing to different base urls using Kotlin and Dagger 2, like this-

```
object Constant {
const val BASE_URL_1 = "https://baseurl1.xyz/"
const val BASE_URL_2 = "https://baseurl2.xyz/"
}


@Provides
@ApplicationScope
@Named(BASE_URL_1)
internal fun retrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, gson: Gson): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder().addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_1)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
}

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
@Named(BASE_URL_2)
internal fun retrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, gson: Gson): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder().addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_2)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
}
```

And then I create the retrofit interfaces-

```
@Provides
@ApplicationScope
fun api_1(@Named(BASE_URL_1) retrofit: Retrofit): Api_1 {
    return retrofit.create<Api_1>(Api_1::class.java)
}

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
fun api_2(@Named(BASE_URL_2) retrofit: Retrofit): Api_2 {
    return retrofit.create<Api_2>(Api_2::class.java)
}
```

Stacktrace -https://gist.github.com/tejasna/18a50cc803116adb48300b7a6d6c98b2

Screenshot
[image: compiler error] -

But im getting a conflicting overload compiler exception.

Advice please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the urls constants are different right?

Comment: show logs please

Comment: Stacktrace? Well, you have two identical method signatures `internal fun retrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, gson: Gson): Retrofit`

Comment: Stack track and screen shot added! Yes i do have two identical method signatures but they are annotated with `@Named`. The url constants are different as well.

Comment: Your code looks ok we may need to see more of it, you can also have a look to my project template maybe it'll help https://github.com/SamYStudiO/beaver